# What's the difference between Maat and Manticore?

Tags: symbolic-execution

Trail of Bits has 2 symbolic execution tools.

- [maat](https://github.com/trailofbits/maat)
- [Manticore](https://github.com/trailofbits/manticore)

What is the main difference between these two? When should someone use what?